# How do I use WhenAny in VB.Net with multiple types?

Tags: .net, async-await

I want to use `Task.WhenAny()` with a list of tasks that have different return types but a common base type.  I'll use `Await` to get the first ready response and cast it from the base type to whatever type I need.  For example, one might be `Task(of ClassDerived1)` and the other `Task(of ClassDerived1)` but I'll call Task.WhenAny(of ClassBase).

Can it be done?  `WhenAny` doesn't support covariance as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it's the `Task<T>` type that doesn't support variance (because there's no `ITask<T>` type). I've run into this same problem and it *is* rather annoying.

Unfortunately, there isn't an ideal solution. I just take the plain `Task` from `WhenAny` and then `as`-cast it to the appropriate type.

**Update from svick's comment:** If you can get every input task to be a `Task<ClassBase>`, then you can get a `Task<ClassBase>` out of `WaitAny`.

If you want to get crazy, you can define your own (awaitable) `IMyTask<out T>` interface, wrap tasks into it, and define your own `WaitAny`. Or make all the tasks `Task<dynamic>`. I haven't tried crazy stuff like this. :)

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier if you made the tasks `Task<ClassBase>`?

Comment: Is this answer still valid or have things moved on in the last 7 years? I have multiple tasks returning different types `e.g. Task(Of String), Task(Of Boolean)` and want to process them as they complete... `Dim CompleteTask = Await WhenAny(AllTasks)` doesn't let me check which task was returned because you can't compare `Task` with `Task(Of String)`, for example.

Comment: @WSC: `Task(Of String)` derives from `Task`, so they can be (reference) compared.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. And that isn't the case for more complex types such as `Task(Of DataTable)`, correct?

Comment: You can equality-compare `Task(Of DataTable)` with `Task`.